# pop_back and erase for a vector class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector

I'm trying to write the pop_back and erase member functions for my vector class. However I realized I can not use delete. Any suggestions for how I can get rid of an element?

```
template <class T>
class Vector{
private:
int current_size, capacity;
T* arr;

public:

Vector();
unsigned int size();
void grow();
void push_back(const T& elt);
void pop_back();
T& at(int pos);
T& front();
T& back();
bool empty();
void insert (const T&elt, int pos);
void erase(int pos);
Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector& v);
T& operator[](int n);

};

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::pop_back(){
if(!empty()){
    delete arr[current_size-1];
    current_size--;
    }
 }

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::erase(int pos){
if(!empty() && pos>=0 && pos<current_size) {
    for (int i=pos; i<(current_size-1); i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    delete arr[current_size-1];
    current_size--;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you `delete` the last element in the `Vector` instead of the element to delete i.e. `arr[pos]` before the loop in `Vector<T>::erase()`?

Comment: How did you realized that you cannot use delete? Compile error? Runtime error? Told by supervisor?

Comment: @MikeCAT First question: because he just shifted them along by one. Second question: presumably a compile error because `arr[current_size-1]` is not a pointer.

Comment: You would use _placement_ new and delete for this.  Depends on how you implemented `grow` though.  That might also be suffering problems.  Writing a vector-style container properly is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

To call the destructor on something not allocated with regular `new` you would do something like this:

```
arr[current_size-1].~T();
```

Keep in mind that when allocating the objects in the array you probably also want to be making sure you call placement `new` on them as well, otherwise you're dealing with uninitialized objects. For example:

```
new (&arr[some_index]) T();
```

(you will need to include the header file `<new>` to do this)

Comment: The only problem with that is that also have to create the destructor myself. So that brings me back to the same issue of how to get rid of those elements.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The code I postedy calls the destructor, and then the code you have already reduces the size variable on your vector. Sure, you have the memory still allocated, but you're not using it which is how vectors work anyway.

Comment: This is bad advice if the asker is using `new T[]` and `delete[]` to allocate and delete the array.

Comment: If he is doing that then he's got bigger problems. Using `new T[]` will construct the objects immediately, which is not what you want for a vector.

Comment: Just to give a little bigger picture: if you want your code to act much like a vector, you 1) allocate raw memory, 2)  construct objects into that memory with placement `new`. 3) Destroy objects by invoking their destructors individually. 4) free an entire chunk of raw memory after destroying all the objects it contained. You can do these directly if you want, or via an Allocator object (that's what `std::vector` does).